# Проверка всех input на пустоту и отображение сообщений об ошибке только у пустых

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, валидация

Если несколько input, рядом с ними сообщения об ошибке, у которых дефолтно display: none

```
<input type="text" name="f_ContactName">
<div class="fail-validation-message">Поле является обязательным для заполнения</div>

<input type="text" name="f_ContactLastname">
<div class="fail-validation-message">Поле является обязательным для заполнения</div>

<input type="text" name="f_Phone" class="phone-mask" placeholder="+7 (      )" maxlength="18">
<div class="fail-validation-message">Поле является обязательным для заполнения</div>

<input type="text" name="f_Email" required="">
<div class="fail-validation-message">Поле является обязательным для заполнения</div>
```

Можно ли сделать проверку на пустоту полей, не создавая для каждого поля своей отдельный if и, соответсвенно показывая сообщение об ошибке только у того input, который не заполнен?

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener('input', () => {
    const message = input.nextSibling.nextElementSibling;
    message.style.display = input.value ? 'none' : 'block';
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  display: block;
}

.fail-validation-message {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="f_ContactName">
<div class="fail-validation-message">Поле является обязательным для заполнения</div>

<input type="text" name="f_ContactLastname">
<div class="fail-validation-message">Поле является обязательным для заполнения</div>

<input type="text" name="f_Phone" class="phone-mask" placeholder="+7 (      )" maxlength="18">
<div class="fail-validation-message">Поле является обязательным для заполнения</div>

<input type="text" name="f_Email" required="">
<div class="fail-validation-message">Поле является обязательным для заполнения</div>
```

Comment: Можно ли реализовать подобную проверку на событие? $(document).on('click', 'li[aria-controls=\'info-tab2\']', function()

Comment: @KBriezy не понял вопроса

Answer (score 1):

быстренько на коленке состряпал

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('input')].forEach(input => {
  const node = input.closest('.form-group');
  
  input.addEventListener('input', function() {
    if (input.value === '') {
      node.classList.add('form-group_error');
    } else {
      node.classList.remove('form-group_error');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.error {
  display: none;
}

.form-group_error .error {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text">
  <span class="error">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text">
  <span class="error">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <input type="text">
  <span class="error">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
</div>
```